# Sencha grid aggregate store entries

Tags: extjs

Let's assume I have a store:

```
Buyer,Good,ItemCount,ItemPrice
{'Alice','Apple',5,$.25}
{'Bob','Pear',2,$.35}
{'Bob','Banana',5,$.25}
{'Bob','Pear',4,$.35}
{'Eve','Grapefruit',2,$.40}
```

And I have a grid in which to display this store's content, and at least a dozen functions scattered all over the place that change this store, changing filters, reloading data from the server, etc.

Is there a fast way to add another grid, which shows every good in a row and every buyer in a column, and how many items of that kind everyone bought in total? This grid should update whenever the original grid is updated.

The way I know, this would require another store, and then I would have to attach to the originalStore's datachanged and filterchanged event and populate the new store by hand every time? Or is there some other solution?

EDIT: I am now looking at pivot grid, as suggested by the first answer, and I have to expand my example a bit, as I stumbled upon a problem I didn't see before:

```
Buyer,Good,ItemCount,ItemPrice
{'Alice','Apple',5,$.25}
{'Bob','Pear',2,$.35}
{'Bob','Banana',5,$.25}
{'Bob','Pear',4,$.35}
{'Eve','Grapefruit',2,$.40}
{{'Alice','Bob'},'Candlelight Dinner Set',1,$45}
{'Eve',{'Ski mask','Baseball bat'},1,$65}
{'Francis',{'Ski mask','Ski poles'},1,$80}
```

Where I would want the dinner to show up at both Alice and Bob, and the products sold in a bundle to show up separately.

Comment: Your `itemPrice` values are not Strings, so you must enclose them in quotes. Monetary values are not native data types in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [PivotGrid](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/components/grids/pivot_grid.html) for your purpose:

```
var pivot = new Ext.grid.PivotGrid({
    store: yourStore,
    aggregator: 'sum',
    measure: 'ItemCount',
    leftAxis: [
        {
            dataIndex: 'Buyer'
        }
    ],
    topAxis: [
        {
            dataIndex: 'Good'
        }
    ]
});
```

### Official Pivot Grid Links:

- [Documentation (Sencha Docs 5.1)](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/components/grids/pivot_grid.html)
- [Announcement (Sencha Blog)](http://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-sencha-pivot-grid/)
- [Download (Free 30-Day Evaluation)](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/pivot-grid-evaluate/)

Comment: Why isn't PivotGrid in the ExtJS 4.2 docs? Could it be that it won't work in Ext 4.2? Otherwise, it looks so good that I had to push my demands even further...

Comment: @Alexander: I added some links to Aniketos' response above. Via Sencha's announcement: *"Sencha Pivot Grid is compatible with Ext JS 4.1.x, 4.2.x, 5.0.x. Compatibility with 5.1 is planned for early Q2."*

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl The PivotGrid that was referenced by Aniketos was for ExtJS 3 and has been abandoned. The new PivotGrid is a different thing entirely. I ended up making my own implementation to populate the grid's store.